# Reactjs to firebase db: Trouble adding multiple children to firebase db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-props

So I was following a simple react/firebase chat room on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or3Gp29o6fE as a reference to what I'm doing with my project. I am making a bug/issue tracker, so that a user can enter a station #, bug/issue, then a description of it. I keep getting an error:

> Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'bugs.0.station'

And I'm not sure how it's undefined if it's just an id number. My end goal at this point in time is to be able to add and remove a bug/issue by id.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import withAuthorization from './withAuthorization';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class HomePage extends Component {
constructor(props,context) {
    super(props,context);
    this.stationBug = this.stationBug.bind(this)
    this.issueBug = this.issueBug.bind(this)
    this.descBug = this.descBug.bind(this)
    this.submitBug = this.submitBug.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        station: '',
        bug: '',
        desc: '',
        bugs: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('bugs/').on ('value', (snapshot) => {
        const currentBugs = snapshot.val()
        if (currentBugs != null) {
            this.setState({
                bugs: currentBugs
            })
        }
    })
}

stationBug(event) {
    this.setState({
        station: event.target.value
    });
}

issueBug(event) {
    this.setState({
        bug: event.target.value
    });
}

descBug(event) {
    this.setState({
        desc: event.target.value
    });
}

submitBug(event) {
    const nextBug = {
        id: this.state.bugs.length,
        station: this.state.title,
        bug: this.state.bug,
        desc: this.state.desc
    }
    firebase.database().ref('bugs/'+nextBug.id).set(nextBug)
}

  render() {

return (
  <div className="App">
            {
            this.state.bugs.map((bug, i) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={bug.id}>{bug.station}</li>
                    )
                })          
            }
            <input onChange={this.stationBug} type="text" placeholder="Station #" />
            <br />
            <textarea onChange={this.issueBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug/Issue" />
            <br />
            <textarea onChange={this.descBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug Description" />
            <br />
            <Button onClick={this.submitBug} type="button"> Enter Bug </Button>
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default withAuthorization()(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looks like a typo. You're referencing `this.state.title` instead of `this.state.station` in your `submitBug` method.

```
class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        station: '',
        bug: '',
        desc: '',
        bugs: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('bugs/').on ('value', (snapshot) => {
        const currentBugs = snapshot.val()
        if (currentBugs != null) {
            this.setState({
                bugs: currentBugs
            })
        }
    })
}

stationBug=(event)=>{
    this.setState({
        station: event.target.value
    });
}

issueBug=(event)=>{
    this.setState({
        bug: event.target.value
    });
}

descBug=(event)=>{
    this.setState({
        desc: event.target.value
    });
}

submitBug=(event)=>{
    const nextBug = {
        id: this.state.bugs.length,
        station: this.state.title,
        bug: this.state.bug,
        desc: this.state.desc
    }
    firebase.database().ref('bugs/'+nextBug.id).set(nextBug)
}

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.bugs.map(bug => <li key={bug.id}>{bug.station}</li>)}
        <input onChange={this.stationBug} type="text" placeholder="Station #" />
        <br />
        <textarea onChange={this.issueBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug/Issue" />
        <br />
        <textarea onChange={this.descBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug Description" />
        <br />
        <Button onClick={this.submitBug} type="button"> Enter Bug </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthorization()(HomePage);
```

Comment: Thank you.. *facepalm* Maybe I need to take a break ha

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explicit:

> Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'bugs.0.station'

Since there's only one call to `Reference.set()` in your code, the problem must be here:

```
submitBug(event) {
    const nextBug = {
        id: this.state.bugs.length,
        station: this.state.title,
        bug: this.state.bug,
        desc: this.state.desc
    }
    firebase.database().ref('bugs/'+nextBug.id).set(nextBug)
}
```

So it seems that `this.state.title` is `undefined`. Most likely you wanted to use `station: this.state.station`.

Comment: Thank you.. Going to take a break from this for a little while ha